# SQL Server : update table if all rows in another table match a criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, `Order` and `Order_Product`. Each product in `Order_Product` has a flag to say if the products data has been emailed or not (`IsEmailed`). If all products on an order have been emailed then I need to change the `Order` table to have an `Order_Status_Id` of 2.

The below code will change the status if `OP.IsEmailed = 1` in any row of the sub query, this is not correct. It needs to change if `OP.IsEmailed = 1` for **ALL** rows in the `Ordered_Product_2016` sub query. Can anyone lend me a hand?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Update_Order_Status 
    @Order_Ids [dbo].Id_List READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Order_2016
    SET Order_Status_Id = 2 -- status of 2 means emails have been sent for all products on this order
    FROM Order_2016
    WHERE Order_Id IN (SELECT Order_Id 
                       FROM Ordered_Product_2016 OP
                       WHERE OP.Order_Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @Order_Ids) 
                         AND OP.IsEmailed = 1)
END
GO
```

**Edit** - I can accomplish it like below but figure there must be a better way.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Update_Order_Status 
    @Order_Ids [dbo].Id_List READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Order_Id FROM Ordered_Product_2016 
                  WHERE Order_Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @Order_Ids) 
                    AND (IsEmailed = 0 OR IsEmailed IS NULL))
    BEGIN;
        UPDATE Order_2016
        SET Order_Status_Id = 2 -- status of 2 means emails have been sent for all products on this order
        FROM Order_2016
        WHERE Order_Id IN (SELECT Order_Id 
                           FROM Ordered_Product_2016 OP
                           WHERE OP.Order_Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @Order_Ids)  
                             AND OP.IsEmailed = 1)
    END;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do what you need:

```
UPDATE O
SET Order_Status_Id = 2
FROM
    Order_2016 O
    JOIN Ordered_Product_2016 OP_Check ON O.Order_Id = OP_Check.Order_Id
    -- the above join is optional; it would prevent the updating of orders having no records in Ordered_Product_2016
    LEFT JOIN Ordered_Product_2016 OP ON
        O.Order_Id = OP.Order_Id
        AND OP.IsEmailed <> 1 OR OP.IsEmailed IS NULL
WHERE OP.Order_Id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, tried the intitial answer and ran into the same issue as the original question

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Update_Order_Status 
@Order_Ids [dbo].Id_List READONLY
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE Order_2016
SET Order_Status_Id = 2 -- status of 2 means emails have been sent for all products on this order
FROM Order_2016 o inner join Ordered_Product_2016 OP on O.Order_Id = OP.Order_Id 
WHERE not (OP.IsEmailed is null or OP.IsEmailed <> 1)
```

I have not tested.  Just give you an idea.